# Product pages throws 404 page not found after data migration from 1.6 to 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, migration, magento2-migration-tool, 404-page

I migrated site from Magento version 1.6.2.0 to Magento version 2.3.1 afterwards when I open all product shows 404 page not found error in front-end

Comment: enable error reporting in boostrap.php file

Comment: Did you add htaccess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to fetch the same issue so Please, a ***check-In Database View*** is created or not ***If a View*** is not there so ***create view after indexing and flush...***
may your issue resolve...
Happy Coding...

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and what fixed it for me was fixing the images, because they got corrupted in the migration.

Comment: please run this command:-  php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento catalog:images:resize